# Discord JS - Command to output randomized array value as command

Tags: javascript, arrays, discord

I'm currently trying to make a command for my bot that gives a randomized answer out of the following array everytime the command is ran:

```
const valMapsList = ['Ascent', 'Bind', 'Split', 'Haven'];
```

I've tried doing this:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = '>!';

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot is now ONLINE!')
});

let valMapsList = ['Ascent', 'Bind', 'Split', 'Haven'];
let map = valMapsList[Math.floor(Math.random() * valMapsList.length)];

client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'map'){
        message.channel.send("Selected Map: " + map);
    } else if (command == 'ping') {
        message.channel.send('Pong!');
    }
});
```

This works but will only give the same answer always as the code is just executed on launch. So I need a function I can call in the

```
if(command === 'map'){
            message.channel.send("Selected Map: " + map);
```

part that will re-run the randomize.

Answer (score 1):

It's always the same value because you have the let out of the message listener.

You need to have this:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = '>!';

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot is now ONLINE!')
});

const valMapsList = ['Ascent', 'Bind', 'Split', 'Haven'];


client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'map'){
        let map = valMapsList[Math.floor(Math.random() * valMapsList.length)];
        message.channel.send("Selected Map: " + map);
    } else if (command == 'ping') {
        message.channel.send('Pong!');
    }
});
```